# Can an Apple Dev Team have one member and have two Team IDs? I believe I do

Tags: xcode, certificate, keychain

I am developing a Mac App. Xcode 12.3 under Big Sur 11.1. I think my Keychain is damaged.

Background: I have recently reset default keychains because a could not silence repeat
Keychain Access requests for a password.

My Team ID is `SOMETHING`,(SEE `SOMETHING_ELSE` 7 lines below.)
When I try to compile the Mac App I get 2 errors:

- No signing certificate "Mac Development" found: No "Mac Development" signing certificate matching team ID "`XXXXXXXXXXX`" with a private key was found.
- The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to log in with account 'APPLE ID HERE'. The login
  details for account "`XXXXXXXXXXXX.com`" were rejected.

I appear to have two Team IDs in setup. That is the following error is displayed when importing a freshly created MAC developer Certificate:

```
Unable to import “Apple Development: Mark Barron (SOMETHING_ELSE)”.Error: -25294
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking on the [error code](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Security/Security-29/Keychain/SecKeychainAPI.h) it looks like you want to add the certificate to keychain that does not exists.

```
errSecNoSuchKeychain -25294 The specified keychain could not be found.
```

It looks like this [issue](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/147491/when-i-try-to-install-my-certificate-in-keychain-the-error-says-unable-to-impo) can be fixed by adding the certificate directly to the `Login` keychain.